# vsftpd: setting up new user for FTP server in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Cannot setup a new user for vsftpd FTP server. My http server's root directory is in /var/www/someuser Main user has it's home directory in /home/mainuser When I login with this user, it's Okay, but I need to get access to /var/www/someuser I did the following:

```
useradd -d /var/www/someuser -p *** someuser
addgroup ftpusers
usermod -aG ftpusers someuser
chown mainuser:ftpusers /var/www/someuser
chmod 0775 /var/www/someuser
```

But when I'm trying to login with vsftpd, it tells that login is incorrect. What I'm doing wrong?

vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=some text
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
check_shell=NO
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd_user_list (empty file)
userlist_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I resolved this problem. Spent some hours resolving problem. The solution was simple: change password of a user with

```
passwd someuser
```

The -p parameter of useradd doesn't work as I can see, although it says that it sets encrypted password of a new account.